# Cannot check value in current iteration of for loop when using any in Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

so I am currently trying to see if a file exists using Python 2.7.5 with the `any` keyword, and if it matches one of the possible variations in my list of possible filenames, to print it out. If none of them exist it should simply print out an error.

So in order to accomplish this I have this code so far:

```
import os
import sys

# globals
base_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Rietty\\'

def main():
        # Get a list of all directories. 
        directories = [dI for dI in os.listdir(base_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(base_dir, dI))]
        # Check if global.xml exists.
        # Check #1 
        for dir in directories:
                filenames = ["global.xml", "globals.xml"]
                this_file = dir + "-base.xml"
                filenames.append(this_file)
                if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(base_dir, dir)): 
                        continue
                if not any(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(base_dir, dir, filename)) for filename in filenames):
                        print("Error" + ": No global(s).xml or *-base.xml file in " + dir + "!")
                else:
                        print(filename) # Errors out here!!

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

And I get an error of:

```
    print(filename)
NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined
```

It works correctly if I take out the else statement, but then only accomplishes half the job, which is checking if files do not exist. I want to know if they exist (there may be more than one) and to add them to a list/tell me which of the three files exist are.

How can I modify my code to accomplish this?

Comment: `filename` is not a local in your function. It is only a local in the generator expression in the `any()` test. Even if it wasn't, if a directory was empty it'd not be set *either*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filename` is not a local in your function. It is only a local in the generator expression in the `any()` test, but generator expressions are executed as if in a separate function. This applies to all names bound to to in a generator expression.

Don't use `any()` here. You want to loop through your `filenames` list, test each, and break out of the loop when you find a match. If you don't find a match, use the [`else:` branch of the `for` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) to print your error. The `else:` branch of a loop is executed when the loop never reaches a `break` statement:

```
    for dir in directories:
        filenames = ["global.xml", "globals.xml", dir + "-base.xml"]
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath = os.path.join(base_name, dir, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(filepath):
                print(filepath)
                break
        else:
            # only reached if no `break` statement was reached
            print("Error: No global(s).xml or *-base.xml file in {}!".format(dir))
```

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Okay so it bugs out a bit in the following ways. 1. If there is no valid file found, the error statement is printed once per item in `filenames` list. (This isn't a big deal.)
2. There is an error for each file that is missing, even if one of the three present exists.

I.e. If there is a global.xml, everything is fine. If there is a globals.xml present then I get an error for global.xml missing (but no error for the -base.xml. If there is only a -base.xml file, I get an error for a missing global and globals.xml

Comment: @Rietty: you have not correctly indented the `else:` statement, you attached it to the `if` test, and not to the `for` loop.

Comment: @Rietty: indentation is *paramount* in Python. Closely read what my answer tells you about how the `for` and `else` lines are indented.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. I will admit I kind of glossed over that on the assumption it worked like other languages. Accepted.